No puedo conectar mi base de datos con el servidor

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user
'alum'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
/var/www/html/mysql/pruebaConex.php:9 Stack trace: #0
/var/www/html/mysql/pruebaConex.php(9): mysqli->__construct() #1
{main} thrown in /var/www/html/mysql/pruebaConex.php on line 9

He intentado todo y no funciona al conectarme vía mysqli y pdo.
Espero acceder a la base de datos y mostrar los datos en el servidor web en respuesta.

El error menciona que el usuario "alumn" no tiene el acceso permitido. Te habrás equivocado en poner "alumno" ?

Saludos. Le sugiero probar con un software (gratuito que hay muchos) usando las credenciales de autenticación respectivas. Puede ser un error de usuario (que no exista), la contraseña es incorrecta (mal proporcionada, no es o no ha sido asignada...) entre otros escenarios.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

El error dice Access denied for user 'alum'@'localhost'. Significa que las credenciales están mal o la aplicación web no tiene permisos para conectarse a mysql con ese usuario. El problema está a nivel de configuración de MySQL o bien estás colocando las credenciales incorrectamente. En el caso de que el servidor de MySQL no sea el mismo de la aplicación, por supuesto que no vas a poder conectarte con un usuario @localhost.
